# ISeditable not working in WebDriverBackedSelenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am recently shifted to WebDriverBackedSelenium from selenium RC. isEditable is not working in it whereas works fine in seleniumRC. Any idea how can I make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `isEditable` is not there in Selenium Webdriver. Instead you can use `Enabled` function. If you have migrated from RC, you can probably define your own function as shown below instead of replacing the existing code.

```
public bool IsEditable(string xpath)
 {
   bool state = false;
   if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Enabled)
   {
    state = true;
   }
   return state;
 }
```

Comment: but .FindElement is also not defined in webdriverbackedselenium. How can I use both webdriverbackedselenium and actual web driver selenium. Confused. Please guide. As currently defined my browser instance as private Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium TargetBrowser { get; set; } which will access only wedriverbackedselenium methods. how can I use both

Comment: Fixed the issue by using @Vikram logic and adding the following to make it work. driver.UnderlyingWebDriver.FindElement(OpenQA.Selenium.By.Id(locator)).Enabled)